# Realization of a data frame with the smallest values grouped by a column

Tags: r, data.table

How can I create a new data frame with the smallest values group by a column.

For example this df:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Gene   Value
A      12
A      10
B      3
B      0
B      6
C      1
D      0
D      4')
```

Now with:

```
test <- setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(Value)], by=Gene]
```

I get this:

```
> test
   Gene Value
1:    A    10
2:    B     0
3:    C     1
4:    D     0
```

But how can I use a second condition for Value > 0 here? I want to have this output:

```
> test
   Gene Value
1:    A    10
2:    B     3
3:    C     1
4:    D     4
```

Comment: Do you want to use the rows with zeros at all? If no why don't you just remove theme beforehand?

Comment: Try `setDT(df)[Value > 0, .SD[which.min(Value)], by=Gene]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you can group, filter and then summarize the min value:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  filter(Value != 0) %>% 
  summarise(Value = min(Value))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Gene  Value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A        10
2 B         3
3 C         1
4 D         4
```

Answer (score 4):

Could do:

```
setDT(df)[, .(Value = min(Value[Value > 0])), by=Gene]
```

Output:

```
   Gene Value
1:    A    10
2:    B     3
3:    C     1
4:    D     4
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Value ~ Gene, subset(df, Value > 0), min)
#    Gene Value
#1    A    10
#2    B     3
#3    C     1
#4    D     4
```